# how can i get JSonArray from the servlet to view in SenchaAchitect?

Tags: javascript, java, tomcat, servlets, sencha-architect

I am trying to create view in senchaArchitect,and i want to do foreach for the Components using jsonArray from the seervlet here is the classe that i used to get information from xml

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        File file = new File("xml.xml"); //request.getParameter("XMLFILE") 
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder loader = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = loader.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());
        DocumentTraversal traversal = (DocumentTraversal) document;
        TreeWalker walker = traversal.createTreeWalker(document.getDocumentElement(), NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL, null, true);
        walker.getRoot();
        Set < String > tagList = traverseLevel(walker, "");

        JSONArray jsonaArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonaArray.addAll(tagList);
        System.out.println(jsonaArray);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and here is my code in SenchaArchitect

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Transaction', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.Transaction',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.view.TransactionViewModel',
        'Ext.form.Panel',
        'Ext.button.Button'
    ],

    viewModel: {
        type: 'transaction'
    },
    height: 796,
    width: 1167,
    layout: 'fit',
    title: 'Transaction',
    defaultListenerScope: true,

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'form',
            layout: 'fit',
            bodyPadding: 10,
            title: '',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    margin: '5 0 0 30',
                    maxHeight: 25,
                    maxWidth: 100,
                    text: 'Tester'
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: 'onPanelAfterRender'
    },

    onPanelAfterRender: function(component, eOpts) {Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/Demo/srvltHTTP',
    success: function(response, opts) {
        function lunchElements(xtype,obj) {
            xtype=textfield;
            dock='top';
            margin='5 0 0 30';
            maxHeight= 20;
            fieldLaberl=response;
        }
       response.foreach(lunchElements);
    },
    failure: function(response, opts) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Erreur','');
    }
});
```